# Custom UINavigationController

Tags: iphone

I'm beginner in IOS
I'm try create custom animation for UINavigationController
Tell me please Apple reject this code or not????

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.5;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewcontroller animated:NO];
```

Thanks!

Comment: How can we determine that what Apple will reject?

Answer (score 2):

like Mike said in his comment: please ask apple and/or take a look at the [iOS App-Store-Review-Guidlines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html)  (if you dont have a developer-account: [google for `app store review guidlines`](http://www.google.com/search?q=app+store+review+guidlines) )

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using any private framework, you are not inheriting the control that apple does not allow to inherit (go to documentation of control you want to customize) you can certainly go and change it.
Now here comes the user experience, apple put a lot of efforts in making the user experience uniform so as far as you are not competing with apple they will be happy to approve your application.
I have seen my initial application got rejected many a time in initial days but now a days they do not put so many specs to dig into the code or other (my belief from the approval speed).
In case of navigation controller I believe you can go and customize it as par your need.